# How to dynamically modify neural network with tensorflow during thetraining

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to dynamically modify the neural network architecture(e.g, add/delete layer...) and hyperparameter during the training period on Tensorflow.(e.g.,control_func(#layer,#neuron,learning_rate...)) However, I have no idea how to implement it in the code. Could anyone can provide some reference, insight, or tutorial? Thanks a lot!